# How to count number of occurrence in a filed table

Tags: mysql

if I have a table with a field City like this:

```
City
------
London
Los Angeles
London
Athens
Rome
Paris
Paris
```

How could I get this result?

```
City   |    CityNumb
-------------------
London      2
Athens      1
Los Angeles 1
Paris       2
Rome        1
```

Comment: Using simple group by , you can achieve this. Before asking question try search on web. Or read a little bit about topic.

Comment: If you don't have a primary key, then you don't really have a table. Anyway, I basically answered this with your last question

Answer (score 2):

```
select City, count(*) as CityNumb
from your_table 
group by City
```

Answer (score 0):

[image][image]

Above image shows the SQL query and results for above task